# cron.weekly does not run

Tags: 11.10, cron, crontab, cron-jobs

I have a shellscript in /etc/myprog/myscript.sh that I would like to run every week. Therefore I created a symbolic link in /etc/cron.weekly:

```
root@ip-10-190-199-197:/etc/cron.weekly# ls -ltr
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 895 2011-07-27 11:32 man-db
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 730 2011-09-24 14:55 apt-xapian-index
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  31 2011-11-17 05:36 myscript -> /etc/myprog/myscript.sh
```

To test it, I did:

```
cd /etc/cron.weekly
sudo ./myscript
```

It works perfect. However, the cronjob never actually runs for some reason. Do I need to do anything to activate cron.weekly?

The contents of my /etc/myprog/myscript.sh is:

```
cd /var/log/myprog/
/etc/myprog/updatescript.sh 1> `date '+/etc/myprog/logs/%Y-%m-%d-cran.log'` 2> `date '+/etc/myprog/logs/%Y-%m-%d-cran-warnings.log'`
```

Comment: Do you run the computer non-stop? Do *anacron* jobs run? Is the `/etc/myprog/myscript.sh` file owned by root? Do you see any messages in *syslog* when the job is supposed to run? Have you tested running it hourly or some other time frame than weekly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to the start of your script to help cron know what interpreter to use. So your script would become:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/log/myprog/
/etc/myprog/updatescript.sh 1> `date '+/etc/myprog/logs/%Y-%m-%d-cran.log'` 2> `date '+/etc/myprog/logs/%Y-%m-%d-cran-warnings.log'`
```

Cron may not know much about paths and the like, so you need to give it more clues.